# Ubuntu freezing on the latest Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS - Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: lenovo, freeze, ideapad

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and deleted all my files and everything and now I'm unable to use the latest version after successful installation. It always freezes and I have to Hard shutdown and turn it back on and as soon as it's on, it freezes again and it only let's me use the Ubuntu interface for a min and then the system is frozen. What to do here?

Comment: The new version seems to be very buggy, my system freezes on the main Ubuntu Start screen, where we see the Logo and Ubuntu written at the bottom. Very bad experience after the installation.

Comment: Hello. Did you verify the ISO before making the live media to do the install? Sounds like you did not. Thousands maybe 10 s of thousands have installed it. It is not buggy.

Comment: I personally downloaded the ISO file and burned it to the flash drive using these steps: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive

Burned the Flash drive using the balenaEtcher application

Comment: So you did not verify it , you should have it sounds like it was corrupt.

Comment: Sorry that you seem to be encountering trouble. There are many possibilities. Maybe the installer was corrupted, maybe you have incompatible hardware, maybe you have a fault, maybe many others. If you boot the LiveUSB (not the installed system) and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment, does that also freeze or crash?

Comment: I think the one I burned it on Flash drive is corrupt, my system is still freezing after Fresh installation. Will try the "Try Ubuntu" option now. I'm using the latest lenovo Ideapad with 8 GB RAM & 2 TB HDD

Comment: Unfortunately "Try Ubuntu" is also freezing (:

Comment: Download the iso again, verify it, "burn" it, verify the medium, and then try it.